# Artifactory & Okta

Tags: authentication, artifactory, okta

Artifactory provides a plugin to use Okta for logins.  However it is set to automatically go to a specific unused on prim site.  Using an Okta custom plugin has allowed for redirection to the home page but not to login.

Has anyone used Okta with artifactory and successfully been able to authenticate and login with an on prim site? If so what steps did you take or what specific website extension did you use?

Comment: Please share what you've done so far

Comment: Used Oktas builtin plugin and Oktas custom used plugin.  Currently it redirects to /#/home instead of /#/login and does not process the username and password.   
what is the -1 for?  I thought the question was worded well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to open a ticket with Okta, sometimes plugins break when a website is updated.

Another option, but it will require some work, is there are templates in Okta that you can use to teach Okta how to sign a User in. If you don't get resolution from Okta, you might do that. Sometimes there are applications that are not in the Okta repository, this allows you to teach Okta how to work with them.

There are two templates, one that does form based authentication (enters the users credentials for them), the other Posts the users credentials with a http-post to the target application (artifactory) in this case.

Comment: Thank you this was very insightful.  We have used the custom app option.  The one issue now is finding the SPID.  The documentation shows for the cloud version but with our on prim version I am not sure how or where to locate the SPID it is looking for.